# Adding non-nullable fields without a default in Django 1.7

Tags: django, django-models

I created the following model to understand how to work with Django properties:

```
from django.db import models
class Person(models.Model):
    _first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='first_name')

    @property
    def first_name(self):
        """This is the getter.  You can add logic too."""
        return self._first_name

    @first_name.setter
    def first_name(self, fname):
        self._first_name = fname
```

Why do I get the following error when I run the "makemigrations" command.  I didn't have to specify default values for fields prior to Django 1.7.  Does it have anything to do with my use of the property decorator?

Thanks.

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field '_first_name' to person without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).  
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default...
 2) Quit...
```

Comment: The error seems quite clear. What do you expect it to do with existing rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is  says that default `models.CharField` has the attribute `blank=False` witch means that it can't store an empty string value and it needs a default value in case it needs to store one, `default="my default value"` witch will be used if it has to store something equivalent to an empty string.
To fix this problem you can do the following

**1)Allow empty strings  values**

You do this by specifying :

```
_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='first_name', blank=True)
```

**2)Set a default value if it encounters and empty string**
You give to him something to use instead of storing an empty string.

You do this by specifying :

```
_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='first_name', default="My default value")
```

By default we cannot store a empty string so we use `blank=True` to allow that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='first_name',blank=False)
```